# Chat connection random exception

Tags: c#, connection, chat, ethernet

I have a connection established through a computer and a lathe for driving corrections.
The connection is an eternet chat done through:

```
public static void StartClient(string strIpAddress, string strPort)
{
    // Connect to a remote device.
    try
    {
        Serializers.Logger.WriteLog("StartClient " + strIpAddress + " port=" + strPort);
        if (strIpAddress.Trim() == "-1")
            strIpAddress = GetLocalIPAddress();

        IPAddress ipAddress = IPAddress.Parse(strIpAddress);
        int port = int.Parse(strPort);
        IPEndPoint remoteEP = new IPEndPoint(ipAddress, port);
        socketClient = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
        socketClient.BeginConnect(remoteEP, new AsyncCallback(ConnectClientCallback), socketClient);
        OnNotification_Client?.Invoke(eSocketOperationType.INFO, "Client connected to " + strIpAddress + " port=" + strPort);
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("StartClient exc:" + e.ToString());
    }
}

private static void ConnectClientCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
{
    try
    {
        socketClient = (Socket)ar.AsyncState;
        socketClient.EndConnect(ar);
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(e.Message); <-------here is fired the problem
    }
}
```

The whole system is part of a cell running 24/7.
Everything works fine but sometimes (more or less once per day) we get the following error:
[image]

My idea is adding a series of pings before the connection in order to understand if the connection is ok. Can a 30 meter long cable running below the cell suffer from random problems?

```
Ping pingSender = new Ping();
int iProblemCounter=0;
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    PingReply reply = pingSender.Send(StrIpAddress);<----Should I here specify a shorter timeout?!?!
    if (reply.Status != IPStatus.Success)
    iProblemCounter++;
}
if (iProblemCounter!=0)
{
    Task.Run(() =>
    {
        var dialogResult = MessageBox.Show("Detected " + iProblemCounter + " problems", "Network problem", MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Warning);
    });
}
```

Additionnaly is there any way to change the code in order to make the connection more robus during the whole process? I get this doubt because while implementing the ping procedure I have seen that it can have a timeout parameter. Could in this case doing the same with a large timeout do the trick?

Thank you in advance
Patrick

Comment: From cmd.exe on both client and server >Netstat -a  and check the status for port 23 when connection fails.  Most likely the connection did not fully close from previous connection so yo uwill wee a TimeError.

Comment: I asked that. But this is an automated cell with operators doing other jobs. So the come there randomly possibly half an hour after the problem. This is why I think about puttig the ping control 1. before the connection 2. when the exception is fired

Comment: Please avoid including images of code or error messages. Also, non-english errors are not very helpful for the majority of posters here.

Comment: This is all I have. The image has been sent me by client. If better I can retype and translated it.

Comment: TCP has a race condition if both client and server attempts to close connection at same time.  With TCP every message gets an ACK.  When both client and server close at the same time one of the ACKS doesn't complete.  Then the connection doesn't fully close.  Some people call this half open half close.  The Netstat results will show a Time Error..  The solution is not to close connection from server.  TCP will not close automatically if the cable is disconnected.  Another solution is to use a Keep-Alive and when the keep alive timeout occurs close the connection.